# Is there an array equivalent to vlookup in vba?

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba

My vba code for a bunch of large ranges uses worksheetfunction.vlookup to find needed values. Ranges can be upwards of 25,000 cells, however, so this takes forever. Is there an equivalent function for arrays?

I've seen lots of SO answers that seem to address returning true/false in there is an exact string match. I need the string's location.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ...

```
Function MyVLook(Arg As Range, Target As Range, ColIdx As Integer) As Range
Dim Idx As Integer

    If Arg = "" Then
        Set MyVLook = [ParamNothing]
    Else
        For Idx = 1 To Target.Rows.Count

            If Target(Idx, 1) = Arg Then
                If ColIdx < 0 Then
                    Set MyVLook = Target(Idx, 1).Offset(0, ColIdx)
                Else
                    Set MyVLook = Target(Idx, ColIdx)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If

        Next Idx
    End If
End Function
```

[ParamNothing] is a single cell range in a worksheet containing some application-specific text; otherwise this works almost like a normal VLOOKUP ... you can specify **negative column offsets** though (something I often miss in regular VLOOKUP), and I didn't built in a flag for range searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the first occurrence try this:

```
Public Sub FindInRange()

    Dim sValueToFind As String
    Dim rRangeToSearch As Range
    Dim rFoundRange As Range

    sValueToFind = "The value I'm searching for"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rRangeToSearch = .Range("A1:A1193")

        Set rFoundRange = rRangeToSearch.Find( _
            What:=sValueToFind, _
            After:=rRangeToSearch.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rFoundRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox sValueToFind & " found in cell " & rFoundRange.Address & _
             " and the value two cells to the right is " & rFoundRange.Offset(, 2), vbInformation + vbOKOnly
        Else
            MsgBox sValueToFind & " not found.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

This will find an exact match due to LookAt:=xlWhole and will not match the case due to MatchCase:=False.  If you want to find the last occurrence use SearchDirection:=xlPrevious.

This mimics using Ctrl + F on the worksheet.
For more info on VBA FIND see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx